# Trying to query data set multiple times

Tags: mysql

What am I doing wrong? Trying to output two COUNTs and need to Group by Grade.

```
SELECT grade, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS total, SUM(case when course like 'AS%'      
then 1 else 0 END) Total_As FROM schedule GROUP BY Grade ORDER BY Grade ASC
```

Only problem is that Total_As is counting grade for multiple instances. Just need to count once if employee took at least one training with Course 'AS%'. The script is currently counting every single 'AS%' taken by employee(ID). Need the "case" part to only count the employee(ID) once to indicate that employee took at least one 'AS%' training or 0 if they did not attend. SUM should not count the employee more than once.

Comment: You cannot perform separate COUNTs in a JOIN because the tables are connected for one count.

Comment: You have a syntax error after the "LEFT JOIN <tablename> ON". Can you clarify what do you want to do?

Comment: Trying to calculate an average based on COUNT from Table. Is there another solution I should pursue?

Comment: Yes you can. but why do you need the "AS" filter?

Comment: Thought I needed to add the AS filter to differentiate the queries off of the same SELECT statement.

Comment: Are you trying to get average scores on all courses, and the average scores for the courses like "AS...."?

Comment: Do you have sample data along with desired output?

Comment: The data is just a list of trainings an employee has taken. The prefix of the training is the "AS". Trying to figure out the percentage of employees within a department (grade) that have taken an "AS".

Comment: Count is a function so you can not do obj.count you need to have COUNT(DISTINCT obj.ID)

Comment: We're close. Need to identify individuals or ID to get the correct COUNT.

Comment: What is grade? This is close  select (select count(ID) as total from schedule) as Total, (SELECT count(ID) from schedule
 where course like 'AS%' and grade = 'A') as Total_AS

Comment: Demodave, you're initial suggestion is working. Just need the count to only count the employee once in the total column. Right now, total is counting every instance of the employee (ID). Only need total to count employee once by department (Grade). SELECT grade, COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(case when course like 'AS%' then 1 else 0 END) Total_As
FROM schedule
GROUP BY grade

Comment: Got it. Thanks Demodave. It is now correct using SELECT grade, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS total, SUM(case when course like 'AS%' then 1 else 0 END) Total_As
FROM schedule
GROUP BY Grade
ORDER BY Grade ASC

Comment: Just found an error. COUNT for Total_as would be incorrect if employee(ID) had multiple "AS". Total_as only has to count employee once. Any help?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected results to better explain what you're trying to do? I don't understand.

Comment: This works: SELECT grade, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS total, SUM(case when course like 'AS%' then 1 else 0 END) Total_As FROM schedule GROUP BY Grade ORDER BY Grade ASC . Only problem is that Total_As is counting grade for multiple instances. Just need to count once if employee took at least one training with 'AS%'. The script is currently counting every single 'AS%' taken by employee(ID). Need the "case" part to only count the employee(ID) once.